# Remove javascript function override

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a java script function override that occurs when certain condition is met. How can I reset these functions to its original state if I don't need it anymore.

```
function setProductFields() {

  if (shouldShow == 'true') {

      selectField = function() {
        //override
      }
  } else {
     selectField() <--- //return to its original state
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to override?

Comment: I've override the selectField() successfully. But I dont need it if shouldShow is false so I want it to revert to original

Comment: why do you want to override existing function ? can you explain the scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save a reference to the old `selectField` in a variable, prior to changing it:

```
var oldSelectField = selectField;

// ... other code ...

function setProductFields() {
  if (shouldShow == 'true') {
      selectField = function() {
        //override
      }
  } else {
     selectField = oldSelectField;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But it is still calling the selectField() inside the setProductFIelds() I've added an alert there

Comment: Oops all good now. I made a mistake calling the backup inside the setProductFields()